# How to recognize if an object is a NSString in this case?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This code

```
if ( [currentValue isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSString")] ) {
            CBDebug(@"this is a string");
```

works well when the type of currentValue is `__NSCFString`

but it doesn't recognize the string if the type is `__NSCFConstantString`

How can I fix it ?
(I'm on OSX)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( [currentValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ) {    
            CBDebug(@"this is a string");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking the textstring of the class, do try the following:

```
[myObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `[obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];`
Normally you only need `NSClassFromString` when testing for class names that may not be available to you.
**Note:** Be careful when using `isKindOfClass:` method on objects represented by a class cluster. Because of the nature of class clusters, the object you get back may not always be the type you expected.   `isKindOfClass:` will return YES if the receiver somewhere inherits from the class passed as argument.